# Concatenate list Object to cypher

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j Bolt Driver and executing few queries where I have to check the node in a list of id's.

Query:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE ID(n) in [1,2,3,4] RETURN n,r,m
```

Doing the same with python fails:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
query = 'MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE ID(n) in '+list+' RETURN n,r,m'
```

The execution fails with this error:

```
query = 'MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE ID(n)' in '+list+' RETURN n,r,m'
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list` is not of type String (str). As there is no natural way of concatenation of `int` and `str`, you're getting this error.

Making `list`  string like `list = '[1,2,3,4]'` would help.

Btw `list` is a reserved keyword in python. You should use a different name.

Comment: neo4j.v1.exceptions.ResultError: End of stream  Facing this error

Comment: The same query returning results in Web console, but throwing exception here in python

Comment: Please either paste the problem here if it's related to the question or open a new one. It sounds like a new problem, as the str/int concatenation is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a driver, you should be using a parameter for this, which avoids all of the string mangling and stringification problems (which are explicitly recommended against):

```
query = 'MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE ID(n) in {id_list} RETURN n,r,m'
params = {'id_list': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
session.run(statement=query, parameters=params)
```

There are several components (labels, relationship types) that cannot be parameterized, but it makes your queries much faster and cleaner to use this feature when possible. Check out [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#cypher-parameters) for more about them.